# Can I avoid storing data on the web by emailing it?

Tags: encryption

My client wants to gather some sensitive info via an app. I don't want to store it on the server. Is this a good plan?

1. Encrypt it on the phone using a public key embedded in the app.
2. Send it to the server.
3. Without saving it, email it to the client.
4. They copy the base64 into a desktop app that decrypts it using a private key stored on the machine.

They already have such data in-house. So I figure this wouldn't be any less secure.

Comment: who is hosting the server? Maybe if your client hosing it then the mobile app should send the data to the server hosted by the client. or the app emails the data directly to the user. Why you have a server in the middle?

Comment: Oh I didn’t realise it was possible to send an email directly from a phone.

Comment: The problem with this is that the device needs email account credentials.

Comment: you can use one email address as the sender, that sends the message directly to the clients (several receivers) and the mobile app should have an email API key not regular conditional. The app could not log in the mailbox  only send emails

Comment: If the email account login was misconfigured then perhaps someone could access it if they fished the details out of the binary. It's academic though because I'm planning to store the encrypted data in the database and have the client accesses the data from a web page.

Comment: which email account, the one used by the app? the one used by the app should not store anything on the mail server. Also, if anything is misconfigured, then the system is not secure anyway. Also, the mobile app should send an encrypted email  message

Comment: Even if the email account used by the app is only a relay, a hacker could fish out the details and use it for sending spam. Why should the email be encrypted if its contents is encrypted?

Comment: Just to be clear, "The web" is sometimes used to refer specifically to devices that communicate via HTTP[S], but sometimes to refer to everything on the Internet. If you're emailing data to somebody (outside your local network), it will always end up on an Internet-connected server - that's just how email works - and it also may be accessed through a web-based interface (Gmail, Outlook Web Access, etc.). If that's OK so long as the data is encrypted end-to-end (only the final recipient can decrypt it), cool, do that. If not, you need a non-Internet way to distribute data.

Comment: I’m going save the data in a database and access it from a web page. That keeps the data in one place where, for extra security, it can be deleted. So yes, no gain in sending by email after all.

Answer (score 2):

I am a strong proponent of *"The best way to protect data at rest is not to store it in the first place"*! Keep it in memory for only as long as you need it.

I like your approach of using encryption to achieve this; if your server only touches the encrypted version, that's equivalent to not touching it at all!

I do have one improvement to suggest though. First, let's take a tangent into [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy); the idea is that every time you encrypt something, you use a temporary disposable key that you don't keep a permanent copy of (aka "one time use" or "ephemeral" key) so that it's very hard for an attacker after the fact to get their hands on the decryption key for some data that they intercepted.

The idea of embedding a public key into the app does not have forward secrecy because you're using the same non-temporary key for every encryption.

## Improvement #1: forward secrecy

1. Phone requests a new ephemeral encryption public key from the server.
2. Phone encrypts the data using the ephemeral public key.
3. Phone sends the encrypted data to the server.
4. Server uses the ephemeral private key (which was only stored in memory as part of the session) to decrypt the data.
5. Server re-encrypts the data for the client.
6. Send the encrypted data to the client however is easiest.

Once the server forgets the ephemeral key from step 4, the encrypted data blob that was sent up from the Android device is unrecoverable, so you don't need to be too careful about whether it ended up in router logs, etc. It's only the key that you need to protect.

If step 4 is public key encryption (ie RSA, and not symmetric encryption like AES) and only the client has the private key, then you could even keep a copy of that encrypted data in case the client needs it re-transmitted. This would be sorta equivalent security-wise to not storing it because you don't have the key to decrypt it.

**Note:** We're basically inventing TLS here, so let's do another version that uses a standard TLS stack rather than inventing our own protocol. We'll find that steps 1, 2, 3, and 4 are all taken care of for us at the TLS (HTTPS) layer.

## Improvement #2: TLS

1. Phone sends the encrypted data to the server over HTTPS.
2. Server encrypts the data for the client.
3. Send the encrypted data to the client however is easiest.

Again, so long as you are careful to re-encrypt the data for the client, and not keep a copy of the plaintext, you'll meet the requirement of "not storing it on the server".

Comment: That’s what I first thought of doing but couldn’t a hacker infiltrate the server and intercept the temporarily decrypted data?

Comment: Also the second part doesn’t pass forward secrecy either. All of the emails previously sent become accessible if the private key is compromised. So maybe my idea fails.

Comment: If storing the encrypted data on the server is safe then the base64 may as well be accessed from a webpage.

Comment: Public key embedded in the app sounds like a no go because there’d be no way to quickly update it if it needs to change.

Comment: Aha.. but I could request the public key from the server and email the data directly from the device. The key pair could be updated regularly.

Comment: But then the phone needs email account credentials. So I think my plan described in the question suffices except the public key is requested from the server instead of being embedded in the app. HTTPS is used regardless. If the data needs to be re-transmitted then the user can re-submit. If this happens often then it could be saved too.

Comment: @IanWarburton I like that you had a conversation with yourself in comments :)

Comment: @IanWarburton 1) Forward secrecy between the phone and your server. That is solved either by generating a new RSA key for each transmission (or just use TLS).

Comment: @IanWarburton 2) Forward secrecy between your server and the client. I didn't touch that in my answer because you didn't provide any details on that part, but yes, that's a valid thing to ask questions about.

Comment: @IanWarburton 3) "what if a hacker infiltrates the server and grabs this data out of memory". If you want to set your bar there, then yes, you need full end-to-end encryption between the phone and your client so that the server never touches the plaintext. That will be a much more complex solution, and probably well into paranoia, unless you're handling military secrets. Even the most highly-regulated things like medical and credit card data doesn't have requirements like that.

Comment: If the data is encrypted on the server then how do you sign it? If the signing key and encryption key are both on the server then surely all a hacker has to do is access the keys, which puts me back to square one.

Comment: 2) I could change the encryption key, say, once a year.

Comment: Also, end-to-end encryption can't be that high end because WhatsApp does it. It's the same encryption code that runs (Xamarin uses .Net - used on the server too), one only needs to fetch the encryption key from the server, which is a simple web request. I think the only complexity is that the key's validation key needs to be embedded in the app.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume no one will tamper with a binary uploaded to App / Play Store.

Comment: @IanWarburton If you're fetching the encryption key from the server, then it's technically not "end-to-end" because the server has the key to decrypt it. If you google _"whatsapp privacy"_ you'll find lots of articles saying that since Facebook bought them, there is no more end-to-end encryption; that facebook employees do have access to all your messages.

Comment: I'm reading it now. But I don't think so... the server has the public encryption key. The client has the corresponding private key installed in their office.

Comment: Ah, ok, fair if it's you're fetching a public key from the server.

Comment: End to end is still working on WhatsApp. In fact, Facebook added the feature to its messaging app. It's called secret conversations. The EU is asking for a back door though.

Comment: This ought to be simpler than WhatsApp because the private key is manually installed. WhatsApp establishes the whole set up over the internet.